# How to open a new datepicker displaying an old date in Android tablet

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I am working on a C# Android tablet project. If I open a new datePicker, it usually displays the current date. I would like to display a specific date (say, 5/9/2010) in the pop up datePicker. How can I do that? I would appreciate if anyone can help out.

Answer (score 0):

I develop android in Java. In my case I use

**`DatePicker.init(year, month, day, DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener)`**

method to initialize the DatePicker before it shows on the screen. I didn't develop android in C#. But I think there must be a similar method to initialize it. Or you can get more information on the API website.